# React Native status bar configuration based on view

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using drawer navigation in my app where my home screen has status bar set to transparent as follows:

Home.js:
`<StatusBar translucent={true} backgroundColor={'transparent'} barStyle="dark-content" />`

If I navigate to another route where I have the same status bar with a different `barStyle`, this works well too:

Second.js: `<StatusBar translucent={true} backgroundColor={'transparent'} barStyle="light-content" />`

However, if I was to return to the home screen (using the drawer), the `barStyle` does not revert back to `dark-content`.

Any idea why this might be happening while the documentation says that status bar colors should change based on route without having to re-render: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/status-bar.html

Comment: Unfortunately I have found that it never works as it should. I fount the best option was to manage it using navigation events. That way you have complete control over it. It is a pain and a little extra boiler plate to your code but it does mean that you are not relying on something else to change it for you.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Andrew in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54581259/react-native-status-bar-configuration-based-on-view?noredirect=1#comment95960064_54581259) above that it's best to manage the `StatusBar` using navigation events, I ended up subscribing to navigation event listeners in order to change StatusBar color and style for each of my views:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const onWillFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
        'willFocus',
        payload => {
            StatusBar.setBarStyle("dark-content");
            StatusBar.setBackgroundColor("transparent");
            StatusBar.setTranslucent(true);
        }
    );
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    onWillFocusSubscription.remove();
}
```